# TypeORM: How to always format database value in where condition for strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I would like to use a generic method "exist" given by TypeORM to verify if name is already inserted in database.

My probleme is that I can't know if name have been inserted in Uppercase or Lowercase and so I can face some false validation and end up inserting twice the same name.

I would like TypeORM and PostgreSQL to always put in lower case the database value (here `name`) while doing the WHERE condition : WHERE "myname" = valueOfDatabase

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ILike` find operator, which will perform a case-ignoring comparison.

There is an example in the [official documentation for advanced find options](https://typeorm.io/find-options#advanced-options):

```
import { ILike } from "typeorm"

const loadedPosts = await dataSource.getRepository(Post).findBy({
    title: ILike("%out #%"),
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to have this but globally, is it possible ?